# ABC is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-roles

I am setting up github action to a aws lambda and getting following error

*Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: github-actions, An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-pipe-PipelineExecutionRole-175Y8M3HIID7J/feature-deployment is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::***:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-pipe-PipelineExecutionRole-175Y8M3HIID7J because no identity-based policy allows the iam:PassRole action*

So I went to this particular role, in IAM->Roles and updated the permissions as below

```
{
        "Action": "iam:PassRole",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-p-CloudFormationExecutionRxxx",
            "arn:aws:iam::YYYY:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-pipe-PipelineExecutionRole-175Y8M3HIID7J/feature-deployment"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

Then tried to add "arn:aws:iam::YYYY:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-pipe-PipelineExecutionRole-175Y8M3HIID7J/feature-deployment" to the trust relationship of this role but it give following error

*Failed to update trust policy.
Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::YYYY:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-pipe-PipelineExecutionRole-175Y8M3HIID7J/feature-deployment"*

But this still gives the same error. Is there something I missing here

Comment: Try removing `/feature-deployment` in `Resources`. Otherwise you have to provide full policies, as from the single snipped you provided its hard to tell what you are even doing.

Comment: @Marcin when remove that part it give this error: "Role arn:aws:iam::***:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-pipe-PipelineExecutionRole-175Y8M3HIID7J is invalid or cannot be assumed"

Comment: Can you check the Trust Relationship tab? Can you try adding AWS":"arn:aws:iam::YYYY:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-dev-pipe-PipelineExecutionRole-175Y8M3HIID7J/feature-deployment?